# Associating one variable with another?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I feel like there's a very simple answer to this but I just can't figure it out. Essentially what I want to do is have one array, for example:

```
char * color[] =
{
"Red",
"Green"
};
```

Attribute to another, for example:

```
char * flavor[] =
{
"Strawberry",
"Apple"
};
```

I would already have "color" output to a text file in a random order, like so:

```
Green
Green
Red
Green
Red
```

But I want the program to be able to distinguish those outputs and make it's own output that is parallel, but with "flavor":

```
Apple
Apple
Strawberry
Apple
Strawberry
```

Obviously outputting "flavor" as random as well won't do the trick, so how do I tell the program which order the first array spits out and tell it to do the same with the other? It's driving me crazy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `std::map`, which is a sort of associative array.

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main (int ac, char **av)
{
  // Set up our map
  std::map<std::string, std::string> color2flavor;
  color2flavor["Red"] = "Strawberry";
  color2flavor["Green"] = "Apple";

  // Read the input, write the mapped output
  std::string quark;
  while(std::cin >> quark)
    std::cout << color2flavor[quark] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll play around with it tonight. I changed a bunch of things and this should work well with it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the c++ language but assume you can use associative arrays if some sort. They have a key and a value, you can output both the key and value as required.

Comment: C++'s `map` could be used for this. See an example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/operator%5B%5D/). The map's key type would need to be changed from `char` to `string` if we're using C++ `string` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an integer Array:

```
int Random[5];
```

then put a random number 0 or 1 in each part of this Array:

`for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
Random[i]=rand()%2;`

then you can write color[i] and flavor[i] to output

Comment: This doesn't associate or attribute anything, it just declares to independent but parallel objects. An associative container, typically std::map, is the correct solution.

Comment: @peachykeen "But I want the program to be able to distinguish those outputs and make it's own output that is parallel, but with "flavor"..." seems to indicate otherwise. The OP seems to want to be able to achieve a certain result, not use a particular data structure.